# Is there a way to make desktop-only CSS rules?

Tags: css, mobile

I found out my Droid has a max width of 800 pixels, which I think some lower-resolution computers are smaller than, but I want my Droid to display the mobile CSS, so I am not sure max device width is the best solution.  So does anybody know how I'd design my CSS link tags so that the mobile CSS is used only by smartphones while the desktop CSS is used only by desktop computers (including the kind with a width under 800px)?

Answer (score 55):

Responsive Web Design, using media-queries

```
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    // this css will only be used when the screen size is min 800px
}
```

Comment: Are there any smartphones that are bigger than 800?

Comment: Yes, the iPhone 4 in landscape mode.

Comment: Oh Sorry Incorrect Comment, that CSS will only show when the css is larger then 800px; Yes if you consider tablets as well..
A cool link is http://mediaqueri.es

Comment: What about iPad in landscape mode? This still falls in this range (iPad Landscape is 1024 px).

Comment: if u resize your desktop navigator, this css will apply

Answer (score 12):

I tried the solutions above, but **they didn't work for iPad in landscape mode**. The iPad Landscape is 1024 px.
So my solution was:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
        .myClass {
            /*...your desktop-only style...*/
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

```
@media (pointer: fine) {
    body {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The gap between mobile and desktop devices is getting closer and closer -consider, for example, tablets or the recently new hybrid devices.

As Aaron points, you might want to define different rules based on device screen (min-width or max-width). Eg:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    // this css will only be used when the screen size is min 800px
}
```

A different criteria you might want to use is targeting devices based on the their screen capabilities:

- [Touchscreen media-queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387805/touchscreen-media-queries)

Comment: I see laptops all the time with touchscreens. I'm not sure that that's a good metric of mobile-ness. Bootstrap, for the record, solves this by having multiple widths it checks for instead.