# Responsive web design: can i detect touch screens?

Tags: html, css, touch

I want to create a website with responsive design. Now I would not only provide different CSS files for different resolutions. Ideally i will also provide different css files for different input devices. For example: Link should be shown larger for touchscreens, as for devices with mouse.

I can detect resolutions with CSS media querys, is there a way to detect touchscreens or general the type of input device?

Comment: no, its about size not about input type.

Comment: but there are also desktop touch monitors, and tablet devices have already partly resolutions >= 1080p.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387805/touchscreen-media-queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a library like modernizr to detect features (like touch) and then apply styles based on that. Check it out here:

http://modernizr.com

Comment: detect modernizr only the browser support for touch events, or also the availability of a touchscreen?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, you might want to test on a touchscreen desktop to be sure about that.

Comment: I have written a test, and it seems to be working. http://www.kevinquiatkowski.de/touchtest/