# Get screen resolution on a mobile website

Tags: javascript, mobile

I am designing a mobile website that has a section to download wallpapers from. In order to accommodate many users, I wish to make it possible to download a wallpaper based on the screen resolution. I want to detect resolution from JavaScript and show the appropriate wallpaper.

This is what I found online and tried and failed xD:

```
width  = window.innerWidth  || document.body.clientWidth
height = window.innerHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
```

For my SGS3, which has the resolution 720x1280 I get the 360x567.

How should I discover the resolution of the phone from JavaScript?

Comment: You should *not* use client-side scripting for this. You cannot assume it is available or giving you correct values. Let the user select what they need.

Comment: I am doing this to make it easier for the user, and if it's not it'll fallback to default resolution.

Comment: It is OK as long as you leave them the choice.

Comment: Try `window.screen.availWidth` and `window.screen.availHeight`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can perhaps use the `screen` object:

```
var w = screen.width;
var h = screen.height;
```

**Update** - Try to use it with the `window.devicePixelRatio`:

```
var ratio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
var w = screen.width * ratio;
var h = screen.height * ratio;
```

Comment: This returns twice a smaller resolution, 360x640 :(

Comment: Great, Ken, this does the job :) Thanks a lot, I've been struggling with this for quite some time :)

Comment: `screen` has always been unreliable. Do not try to detect what the user can select.

Comment: @Ken What is the purpose of the ratio addition?

Comment: @jimirings its for screens which uses different ratio (ie. retina screens which are 2:1) than the normal 1:1 in which case you need to scale the w/h accordingly to fill the same space.

Comment: Some Android devices return real device height and width, and if you multipy ratio that will be fault. and seems to no better way to resolve it.

Answer (score 7):

Ken Fyrstenberg, great stuff, thanks. I was looking for an easy way to detect all the possible screen size and resolution data, and to answer the question of what the ratio is good for, it lets you see if it's for example a retina display type high resolution device.

```
wh:768x1024 cwh:768x905 rwh:1536x2048 ts:touch
```

combined with the touch tests check this related [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387805/media-query-to-detect-if-device-is-touchscreen#):

I can get a very good sense of the actual screen/touch specs of the devices our real users are running.

for web stuff, of course, what you really are interested in is the size of the actual browser inner window, the space you are allotted on the device that is. Just as an aside, I've already seen that apple devices appear to always give the portrait mode dimensions, eg, 768 x 1024 for a non retina display iPad, which is a bit annoying because I was hoping to also learn how most users actually interact with the web and our site.

Android seems to give the actual width/ height of that moment, ie, either landscape or portrait width/height.

For example:

```
var ratio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
var is_touch_device = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;
var touch_status = (is_touch_device) ? 'touch' : 'no-touch';
touch_status = ' ts:' + touch_status;
var width_height = 'wh:' + screen.width + 'x' + screen.height;
var client_width_height = ' cwh:' + document.documentElement.clientWidth + 'x' + document.documentElement.clientHeight;
var rw = screen.width * ratio;
var rh = screen.height * ratio;
var ratio_width_height = ' r:' + ratio + ' rwh:' + rw + 'x' + rh;
var data_string = width_height + client_width_height + ratio_width_height + touch_status;
```

This creates a lot of data about the client system which you can then pass to something using whatever method you like.

UPDATE:
It just took a few minutes using this method to find how apple devices actually report their width/height:

```
wh:375x667 cwh:667x375 r:2 rwh:750x1334 ts:touch Device type: mobile
```

As you can see, the `document.documentElement.clientWidth` method reports the actual width if portrait/landscape, good stuff.

Answer (score 3):

This will work in **mobil device** too

```
screen_width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
screen_heght = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.screen.width` and `window.screen.height` to detect the screen resolution of the device.

Comment: This returns twice a smaller resolution, 360x640 :(