# Reliable code to detect screen width & height on all browsers in 2017 (especially Android phones)?

Tags: javascript

I am currently using this code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17359959/5712410)

```
var ratio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
var w = screen.width * ratio;
var h = screen.height * ratio;
```

It works on desktop firefox, but not on my android browsers (stock or chrome on my Samsung Galaxy S5 phone updated to android 5). I get 320x640 instead of 1280x1920.

Is there a reliable solution to detect screen sizes accross all devices & browsers? I need screen width of device, not inner/client widths or something else.

If it's not possible, several comments saying this is not possible from influential SO members would work fine - I could show this as proof to my client.

Comment: check [this file](https://github.com/tysonmatanich/GetDevicePixelRatio/blob/master/getDevicePixelRatio.js) which might be a potential solution. Haven't tested it myself. This appears also in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063489/how-can-you-get-the-css-pixel-device-pixel-ratio), answer by abhinav sharma.

Comment: As far as I have dag, there is no real solution to this problem @MarkoAvlijaš

Comment: @andreim - this is working on my phone. Are you going to create an answer?

Comment: @MarkoAvlijaš I don't feel like creating an answer as I haven't come with anything new other than referencing another answer. If you'd like you can create an answer providing your testing results. That might bring something new to the table and I will be here to upvote ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to fix obtaining of device-pixel ratio is described [here](https://github.com/tysonmatanich/GetDevicePixelRatio/blob/master/getDevicePixelRatio.js):

```
/*! GetDevicePixelRatio | Author: Tyson Matanich, 2012 | License: MIT */
(function (window) {
    window.getDevicePixelRatio = function () {
        var ratio = 1;
        // To account for zoom, change to use deviceXDPI instead of systemXDPI
        if (window.screen.systemXDPI !== undefined && window.screen.logicalXDPI !== undefined && window.screen.systemXDPI > window.screen.logicalXDPI) {
            // Only allow for values > 1
            ratio = window.screen.systemXDPI / window.screen.logicalXDPI;
        }
        else if (window.devicePixelRatio !== undefined) {
            ratio = window.devicePixelRatio;
        }
        return ratio;
    };
})(this);
```

Therefore the complete code would be:

```
var ratio = window.getDevicePixelRatio();
var w = screen.width * ratio;
var h = screen.height * ratio;
```

**NOTE:** This solution is referenced also in this [question answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063489/how-can-you-get-the-css-pixel-device-pixel-ratio) by abhinav sharma.