# javascript detect desktop touch and mouse support

Tags: javascript, touch, browser-feature-detection

How should touch-enabled devices be differentiates between pure touch and ones that also have a mouse? (like some of today's laptops)

There is a need to give all mouse functionality a priority in an application, and if the device running the app has only touch support, to change the functionality.

If a touch-device also has a mouse pointer, logic suggests the app should consider that device as a normal desktop, and might add touch support as well, but the styling itself should respond to mouse events.

normal touch detection is achieved like so:
`'ontouchend' in document;`

One way to detect if the computer is desktop might be to check the screen resolution:

```
window.screen.width >= 1280 // desktop
```

but that is not so good because some devices might have very large **viewport** resolution, and some laptops might have low resolution...

Comment: this post is related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7838680/104380

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21054126/how-to-detect-if-a-device-has-mouse-support

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some research, I have found that the best solution was to use this code:

**https://github.com/matthewhudson/device.js**

So, the way it works, is by giving the body element class names which represent the device and orientation, and with that I can pretty much guess if the user has a mouse. (class `desktop` is applied)

Comment: what about touch screen desktop,laptop monitors

Comment: what about them? try and see

Comment: lets say you detect mouse and enhance ui for mouse, but user is using monitor for navigating, and wanted it to work like on tablet.

Comment: you need to have 3 modes, one for only mouse, one for only touch and one for both, which is the most difficult to create. Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: yea lets say i want vertical navigation menu to move opposite of mouse, as in mac, to assist user reach their target. But if user is using touch then i just want them to drag menu up and down. Now i have seen a new feature that's not touch, click or drag. It's hover. In some samsung phones. This is akin to moving mouse...lets ignore that for now

Comment: I don't understand what is your question? implementation of use-cases is irrelevant to this question. It's about detection of device capabilities only.