# How to detect global mousemoves in React?

Tags: reactjs

Inside a component I need to know if the browser has a mouse or not, it affects the component.

My plan is to listen for global mousemoves, but I'm not sure how I should do this in react. I could do something like this inside the component:

```
window.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);
```

but I'm not sure if it's a good idea. The component will be used lot's of times on the same page, so maybe I should put it in a component of it's own somehow?

Comment: You can create one non react object with event listener and then pass data to you components via props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the JavaScript world, **there isn't a reliable way** to catch if the user has a mouse or not. There are related discussions on this topic in [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21054126/how-to-detect-if-a-device-has-mouse-support) [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838680/detecting-that-the-browser-has-no-mouse-and-is-touch-only) [places](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/869). But you already know that.

Having this in mind, I see **two important considerations** in order to **not cause performance issues** while implementing your plan to listen for global mousemoves.

1. Kill the event listener immediately after it executes the first time.

   ```
   let hasMouse = false;

   const hasMouseCheck = () => {
       hasMouse = true;

       // Kill the event listener, so it executes only once
       window.removeEventListener('mousemove', hasMouseCheck, false);
   };

   window.addEventListener('mousemove', hasMouseCheck, false);
   ```
2. Put your logic in a place where it will execute only once, when your application loads. A good place is the [`componentDidMount` lifecycle hook](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) on your entry (main) component. That's a method invoked only once, immediately after the component is mounted. From there on, pass it to whichever component you need.

   Or, of course, you could just place the above snippet in an external javascript file (without creating a ReactJS component), and set the `hasMouse` flag in the global `window` scope. Then, access it via `window.hasMouse` from whichever component you need, again.

   **Implement the approach that makes the most sense to you for your specific use-case**. The important thing is to make sure the logic executes only once ;-)