# Bootstrap3 - Disable Popover on mobile devices

Tags: android, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, popover

I'm using the popover in hover mode when the mouse moves over the buttons of social networks. This works well in the browser but would like to be disabled in mobile devices or to be more exact, on devices that do not use mouse.

```
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex2-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav textomenu">
                <li><div id="example" data-trigger="hover" data-content="Comparte esta página!" data-original-title="Amixer Music" class="fb-like botonlike" data-href="http://www.traductoramixer.es/amixermusic/" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div></li>
                <li><div id="example2" data-trigger="hover" data-content="Unete a nosotros!" data-original-title="Traductor Amixer" class="fb-like botonlike" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/traductoramixer.es" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div></li>
                <li><div id="example3" data-trigger="hover" data-content="Sigueme!" data-original-title="Kokox - Webmaster" class="fb-follow botoncomparte" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/elkokox" data-colorscheme="light" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="false"></div></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <script>
          $(function (){
             $("#example").popover({

                placement: 'bottom'
             });

          });

          $(function (){
             $("#example2").popover();
          });

          $(function (){
             $("#example3").popover({
                placement: 'top'
             });
          });
      </script>
```

I have taken this decision because in the small screens, popover leaving margin and I think his use (hover mode) is unnecessary for devices that do not use mouse.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387805/touchscreen-media-queries).

You can use [**Modernizr**](http://modernizr.com/) to detect is device a touch device and based on it activate or no activate `popover`

## JavaScript:

```
if (Modernizr.touch) {
   // activate popover
}
```