# CSS - Show elements on touchscreen devices only

Tags: html, css, touchscreen

I've got layout in which 80% of buttons are icons with tooltip describing the function appearing on :hover

Is it possible using CSS and Media Queries only to show additional class (for example `.button-info`) if  website is viewed on touchscreen device. Other than guessing by the resolution and orientation what sort of device user might be using?

Comment: Have you tried using `:focus`?

Comment: Since that would require detecting if it's touch enabled, try this thread; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817029/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-a-touch-screen-device-using-javascript

Comment: how can :focus be used for that purpose?

MrMarlow, I wanted to avoid using jQuery for that.

Comment: `a:focus + .button-info {}` or `a:focus ~ .button-info {}`, depends on where your button is

Answer (score 3):

What you are requesting is **being developped** by the W3C for CSS4: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/mediaqueries-4/#pointer

You'd use :

```
@media (pointer: coarse) and (hover: none) {
    /* your touchscreen specific rules */
}
```

But it is **NOT** available right now, so you'll have to use a workaround, with device widths and orientations.

**NB:** That is if you want to use a CSS only solution.

Comment: Your answer __maybe__ will be useful in the future, but I don't see a point posting it right now.

Comment: OP's asking if there's a native, non-hacky CSS way to detect touchscreens, and i'm answering.

Comment: Would you accept your own answer if it doesn't solve the problem at the moment?

Comment: I would if i already had a solution but was hoping for a better one.

Comment: Actually I think that answer stating that there is no such solution because it is being developed is actually very useful, as it can save time on further googling.

Comment: Works in 2018! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Similar to this question ([Media query to detect if device is touchscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387805/touchscreen-media-queries))

This guy has some good points that you should consider.

http://www.stucox.com/blog/you-cant-detect-a-touchscreen/

He talks about the various ways of achieving what your trying to do, then explains what the pitfalls are. Ultimately concluding that if your trying to detect if it's a touch screen then your probably going about it the wrong way anyway.

Consider treating all users as touch screen users because not everyone looks around the screen with the mouse cursor.