# Setting overflow-scrolling to touch on iPad overrides all custom css set for webkit-scrollbar, is there any fix for this?

Tags: css, ipad, scroll, webkit

If I set the following css for a div:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

the custom css I use for hiding the scrollbar gets overridden and the default scrollbar appears on iPad.

This is the css I use to hide the scrollbar:

```
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
    opacity:0;
  }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      opacity:0;
  }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      opacity:0;
  }
```

If you know any solution to override the default scrollbar when the overflow-scrolling is set to touch, I would be grateful for your help.

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting thing is 2 of 10 times, the scrollbar disappears and it works as intended. Quite odd.

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16671476/5090789) to a similar question.  It seems that setting `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` to `touch` will enable iOS native scrollbars, ignoring other CSS rules.  You can get around that by nesting your scrolling area div with a slightly smaller, `overflow: hidden` div, effectively cutting off the scrollbars where needed.

Comment: Wouldn't you have big issues with this about crossbrowsing (FF, Opera)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a look on some [jQuery custom content scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/#plugin-data-contentTouchScroll) plugins and especially with the options like `contentTouchScroll: integer` which might help you to detect the touch screens and then play with this.

OR

Otherwise, and probably a better solution, you should (like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11387852/3132641)) use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/docs/).

```
if (Modernizr.touch){
   // bind to touchstart, touchmove, etc and watch `event.streamId`
}
```

Why not using both of them with

```
if (Modernizr.touch){
   $(".content").mCustomScrollbar({
       contentTouchScroll: false
   });
}
```

Good Luck'

Comment: @skywlkr Have you fixed your issue with this? May I ask for the bounty, Mr Jango Fett? ☞  ͜ʖ  ☞