# How to display different image based on rendering device(touchbased/non touch based) using bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following css class:

```
.watermark {      
  background-image: url('Images/MyImage.svg');      
}
```

Now, I want to render different image based on the device[touch/non touch based].
Is it possible through bootstrap?
Or  Javascript/JQuery is the only option?
Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11387852/853295