# Detect if a physical mouse or trackpad is present in css or javascript

Tags: javascript, css, touch, modernizr

My website have two versions, for desktop and mobile. The most commom way of determining which version i should display is by checking if touch is enabled, for instance using `touch` of modernizr.

What I want is that i could display my desktop website even if touch is enabled, for some windows notebooks for instance, that are touchscreen but also have a mouse/trackpad. So it would come down to detecting if a mouse/trackpad are present, even if touch events also are. So:

- Is there any way of doing this?
- If not, what's the most approximate way?

---

Just to make it more clear: Most differences are about the UX of input through mouse or touch, like displaying information on mouse hover, and not only layout related.

Comment: `var hasMouse = confirm('Are you using a mouse or other pointing device (that isn\'t touch)?');`

Comment: [CSS solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14457567/4578017) [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40media/any-pointer)

Comment: I  don't think this is a duplicate:  a trackpad is not a touch device.