# CSS media queries: simulate pointer:fine in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, media-queries

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44197598/7445359) answer, there is nonstandard support for `pointer:coarse` in Firefox using `-moz-touch-enabled`.

Is there any similar way to simulate `pointer:fine` using this or any other property in Firefox?