# How to make the background of website changes when opened with phone?

Tags: html, css, mobile, background, resolution

i need to know how to make the web page background changes when the it's opened with a phone

this is my try but it didn't work :

```
<style>
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    background-color: blue;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Well, you can't explicitly test for phones, only for screen sizes and orientations with css. 

Btw, you closing } is missing on the @media query. That should solve it.

Comment: refer this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/11387805/17033432